# Why does my first click on the + button not increase the value of the input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a quick script that will update the number in the `<input>` field between the 2 buttons, but when I click the `+` button initially it doesn't work, after the first press it begins working as expected from the 2nd click and for the rest of the clicks. Clicking the `-` button first works as expected.

```js
// click + button
$(".inc").click(function(){
  service = $(this).closest(".service-option-card");
  let quantity = getCurrentQuantity(service);
  let newQuantity = quantity+1;

  setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  updatePrice(newQuantity, service);
});

// click - button
$(".dec").click(function(){
  service = $(this).closest(".service-option-card");
  let quantity = getCurrentQuantity(service);
  let newQuantity = quantity-1;

  if(newQuantity <= 0) {
    let newQuantity = 0
    setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  } else {
    setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  }

  updatePrice(newQuantity, $(this).closest(".service-option-card"));
});

// Get current number
function getCurrentQuantity(service) {
  let quantity_str = service.find(".quantity").val();
  quantity_num = Number(quantity_str);
  return quantity_num;
}

// Set new Number
function setNewQuantity(quantity, service) {
  service.find(".quantity").val(quantity);
}

// Update Price
function updatePrice(quantity, service) {
  var price = parseInt(service.find(".price").val().replace(/,/g, ""));
  var total = quantity * price;

  if(total < 0) {
    total = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="service-option-card" data-monthly="10">                             
  <div class="quantity">
    <button class="btn btn-quantity dec">-</button>
      <input class="quantity-input quantity" value="1">
    <button class="btn btn-quantity inc">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a simpler alternative, you could use a [number input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason here is that you're using the class `.quantity` to get the `input`'s value that happens to be also set to the `input`'s parent `div` so when `let quantity_str = service.find(".quantity").val()` is executed, precisely the `find` method that is called on `service`, the `div` with class `.service-option-card` which is the parent of both the `div.quantity` and `input.quantity`, then `find` method will match both the the `div` and the `input` thus you won't get the `input`'s value as expected.

There are many fixes, a quick solution is to prefix the `.quanity` selector with `input` (becomes `input.quantity`) to only target the `input` and thus you get the expected result.

Here's a demo with the fix  applied:

```js
// click + button
$(".inc").click(function(){
  service = $(this).closest(".service-option-card");
  let quantity = getCurrentQuantity(service);
  let newQuantity = quantity+1;

  setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  updatePrice(newQuantity, service);
});

// click - button
$(".dec").click(function(){
  service = $(this).closest(".service-option-card");
  let quantity = getCurrentQuantity(service);
  let newQuantity = quantity-1;

  if(newQuantity <= 0) {
    let newQuantity = 0
    setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  } else {
    setNewQuantity(newQuantity, service);
  }

  updatePrice(newQuantity, $(this).closest(".service-option-card"));
});

// Get current number
function getCurrentQuantity(service) {
  let quantity_str = service.find("input.quantity").val();
  quantity_num = Number(quantity_str);
  return quantity_num;
}

// Set new Number
function setNewQuantity(quantity, service) {
  service.find("input.quantity").val(quantity);
}

// Update Price
function updatePrice(quantity, service) {
  var price = parseInt(service.find(".price").val().replace(/,/g, ""));
  var total = quantity * price;

  if(total < 0) {
    total = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="service-option-card" data-monthly="10">                             
  <div class="quantity">
    <button class="btn btn-quantity dec">-</button>
      <input class="quantity-input quantity" value="1">
    <button class="btn btn-quantity inc">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> The line `var price = parseInt(service.find(".price").val().replace(/,/g, ""))` throws an error because your `HTML` doesn't have an element having the `price` class which leads to trying to execute `replace` method on `undefined`.
>
> Anyway, I just wanted to warn you about that, the fix is out of the scope of my answer (though I'll happily provide further help if needed).

Answer (score 2):

Its breaking because your input element has a class .quantity which is also a class on a div element. The find method in the functions setNewQuantity() and getCurrentQuantity() are picking the div which evaluates its value to 0 because value doesn't exist for the div tag.
On the first click, the zero evaluates to 1 which also is the value in your input tag, hence it doesnt seem to have a visual effect.
change your functions to

```
// Get current number
function getCurrentQuantity(service) {
    console.log({service})
    let quantity_str = service.find("input.quantity").val();
    console.log({quantity_str})
    quantity_num = Number(quantity_str);
    return quantity_num;
}

// Set new Number
function setNewQuantity(quantity, service) {
    service.find("input.quantity").val(quantity);
}
```

Comment: Good spot +1, but it would help to explain to OP why it starts working after the first click.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're using `Number()` in your `getCurrentQuantity()` function.

Comment: can you elaborate?